# How to integrate bootstrap-tour to angular app?

Tags: angular

Im trying to use the [bootstrap-tour](http://bootstraptour.com/) to my angular app so i´ve added it to my bundle:

```
   //css
   "../node_modules/bootstrap-tour/build/css/bootstrap-tour-standalone.css"

   //js  
   "../node_modules/bootstrap-tour/build/js/bootstrap-tour-standalone.js"
```

Then in my component i tried to make a simple tour:

```
     ngAfterViewInit() {
       let tour = new Tour({
       name:'tour',
       template: `<div>
           <h3>Test</h3>
         </div>`,
       steps: [
        {
            element: "#test",
            title: "Title of my step",
            content: "Content of my step"
        }
      ]
     });           

      tour.init();
      tour.start();
   }
```

But on my console i get the error: 
**vendor.bundle.js:149550 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'backdrop' of undefined
at Tour._showPopoverAndOverlay**

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? You have jQuery how to dependency in your App?

Comment: im on version 4.4.3, and yes, my component has Jquery Available. Its in the bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is that Tour class, which is coming from the bootstrap-tour package, is not known to typescript. What you have to do:

Inside the component,

```
declare var Tour: any;
```

Then the ngAfterViewInit() part, do the initialization:

```
this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    this.tour = new Tour({                           
        debug: true,
        storage: false,                        
        backdrop: true,
    });
    this.tour.addStep({
        element: ".tour-nav-1",
        title: "Title of my step 1",
        content: "Content of my step 1",
        placement: 'bottom',
        backdrop: true,
    });
    this.tour.addStep({
        element: ".tour-nav-2",
        title: "Title of my step 2",
        content: "Content of my step 2",
        placement: 'bottom',
    });
    // Initialize the tour
    this.tour.init();
});
```

and voila, you're all set. Note that the this._ngZone is the ng zone which you can instantiate inside the constructor of the component like this:

```
constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}
```

You can then run the

```
this.tour.start(true);
```

command anywhere inside the component to start the tour, just make sure the this.tour.init() is called before the this.tour.start() .

Note that the this.tour is a component class variable that is declared as:

```
tour: any;
```

I have tested this to be working fine with bootstrap-tour version 0.12.0 and angular version 6.0.0. It should work just fine for any angular versions > 2

If you have any questions, just ask.

Comment: Did you implement the redirect part to change the pages for tour? How did you use Angular Router for redirection?

Comment: I did not implement the redirect path but
`
this.tour4 = new Tour({
    name: 'page4tour',
    debug: true,
    storage: false,
    onEnd: this.onTourEnded.bind(this),
    backdrop: true,
});
`
, you could end the current route tour, and in the onTourEnded handler, route to the destination route and start a new tour keeping in mind the previous route ending to give a continuation feeling to the user. Just my two cents.

Comment: I was able to achieve my required functionality with [Ngx Tour](https://isaacplmann.github.io/ngx-tour). It's a great library and gives option to navigate during a tour and plays well with Angular and Ngx Bootstrap.

Comment: I am getting Tour is not defined event I declared as above

Answer (score 1):

Niz is correct but **one more** important note to add is NOT to import the bootstrap-standalone file into the component.  I was doing that and putting it in the bundle in the `.angular-cli.json` file as well and it wasn't working correctly.

I'm guessing that since it found a reference for Tour inside the component then the

```
this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular
```

wasn't really doing anything.